# jenkins and Jenkins-Reviewbot

Tags: jenkins, review-board

I want to use Jenkins-Reviewbot plugin. The problem is that we need to duplicate builds - one with parameterized build and other normal otherwise build fails. Is there a way I can not give review URL and build will still run without reviewboard URL successfully?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A solution for the problem could be define de "core job" as a non parameterized job, this job will perform your main task (as compile, past the unit test, etc.).

Then you can create another job with the url review parameter, that use the same workspace that "core job". This second job receive the review url parameter and execute the tasks:
- apply the patch
- execute the "core job" 
- perform the post build actions, like write the result to review board

Comment: well the problem is that, that's exactly organization I work for do not want - have additional jenkins job. We want to use only one job, use reviewboard plugin but be able to give no url and job should still succeed.